# pass named arguments from a route to a controller

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

Given the following Controller:

`class Page {
    public function about($section){
        switch($section){}
    }
}`

How can I pass the a value to Page->about() directly from `$f3->route`?

Comment: vague assertion bad boy. You never really used it, did you?

Comment: @ikkez who is bad boy?

Comment: oh nvm, he must have deleted his condescending comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fat-Free will populate two parameters to each routing handler. So when you got this route:
`$f3->route('GET /about/@section','\Page->about');` it will call your function with 1st parameter being the framework instance and 2nd is an array of all routing arguments.

```
class Page { 
  public function about($f3, $args){
    switch($args['section']){} 
  } 
}
```

See http://fatfreeframework.com/routing-engine#RoutesandTokens for more details.